# vsftpd : limit connection to a set of IP addresses

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

Is it possible to setup vsftpd to only accept connections from a certain set of IP addresses?

I've looked at the /etc/vsftpd.conf for options but there is no hint at that. The manual does not either.

My  Server OS : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Seems you can use `TCP Wrappers` (just tested it on my Ubuntu) and use `hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` to filter vsftpd access.

Add the following to your `vsftpd.conf` file :

```
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

Restart vsftpd.

In `/etc/hosts.deny` deny everyone for vsftpd :

```
vsftpd: ALL
```

Then, in `/etc/hosts.allow` add the authorized IPs :

```
vsftpd:192.168.0.39 192.168.0.50
```

Comment: actually, it does not work. I can still access the server even though my IP adress is not one of the addresses listed in hosts.allow.

Comment: nevermind: it works. Just be aware that you need to add a newline underneath the last command in your hosts.* files. (source: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-tcpwrappers.html)

Comment: @pixeline Wow great and thanks for the info ! i admit i used to press "enter" each time i write a line in a file, so i didn't see this issue. Thanks for the tip ! Cheers